# Filling HashMap by reference

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap which I pass it to a function to fill it by reference like this,

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
    loadCache(memorySubscriberValues);
memorySubscriberValues.size();// size remains zero
```

and in the loadCache method I fill this HashMap and as i think it should be filled by reference

```
   loadCache(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues) {
       memorySubscriberValues = mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition);
}
```

The HashMap is filled in the loadCache method, but going back to caller method to check it, I found that its size is 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a classic java mistake assuming you can re-assign method parameters, and have that change be reflected in the caller.

```
   memorySubscriberValues = mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition);
```

If you reassign this parameter, it will **only** be reflected on this current stack frame. If you want to alter the parameter, you need to actually use `memorySubscriberValues.put` inside the method.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that is

```
mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition);
```

creates a ***new instance*** that is local to your method. if on the other hand you would add that result to the map that you have passed to the method - then you would be ok

see [Passing Reference Data Type Arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Answer (score 0):

Java does not allow you to reseat references since it is pass by value. So references are also passed by value. Hence the `memorySubscriberValues` in `loadCache` is a local reference and you're simply re-assigning it to point to the `HashMap` instance returned by `mainDao.getData`. This doesn't affect the reference of `memorySubscriberValues` in the parent method which points to the new `HashMap` instance. I would modify your code to do this instead:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues = loadCache();

public Map<String, Map<String, String>> loadCache(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues) {
       return  mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition);
}
```

This way you're assigning `memorySubscriberValues` in the parent function to point to the `Map` returned by `mainDao.getData(...)`.

On another note, it is better to type your collections by interface instead of the concrete type (i.e., `Map` vs `HashMap` or `List` vs `ArrayList`). This way it is easy for you to swap out implementations later and your design is not tightly coupled to a particular implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your method doesn't fill the map that is passed as argument. It assigns a new map to the reference that is passed. And references are passed by values. So the original HashMap is left untouched.

You should simply return a map from your method:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues = loadCache();

...

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> loadCache() {
    return mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass `memorySubscriberValues` to `loadCache` it creates a copy on which it works. Try this:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues = loadCache(memorySubscriberValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're simply re-assigning the `memorySubscriberValues` variable to reference a *different* HashMap. What you want to do is add all the entries from your `mainDao` into the HashMap that you passed in as an argument:

```
void loadCache(HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> memorySubscriberValues) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> i : mainDao.getData(MSISDN_partition_prefix, MSISDN_loading_prefix, endIndexPartition).entrySet()) {
        memorySubscriberValues.put(i.getKey(), i.getValue());
    }
}
```

By calling `put` on the same reference that was passed in to the method, all of the changes will be reflected in the original HashMap. If you re-assign the variable `memorySubscriberValues`, then any changes you make to it will be reflected in whatever map it is now referencing.